# Should I write these Test Cases?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing

Here's the schema of the model I want to test:

```
create_table "retreats", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.string   "tagline"
  t.string   "type_of"
  t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
  t.string   "description"
  t.string   "schedule"
  t.boolean  "available",   default: true
end
```

Here's the Retreat model:

```
class Retreat < ApplicationRecord
  TYPES_OF_RETREATS = ['individual', 'group']
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :type_of, presence: true, inclusion: {in: TYPES_OF_RETREATS,
    message: "%{value} is not a valid type."}

  has_many :testimonials, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :images, dependent: :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :dates, class_name: "RetreatDate", foreign_key: 
   'retreat_id', association_foreign_key: 'retreat_date_id'
end
```

These are the test cases I've written:

```
  test "retreat should not save without a title" do
    retreat = retreats(:no_title)
    assert_not retreat.save, "Saved a retreat without a title"
  end

  test "retreat should not save without a type" do
    retreat = retreats(:no_type)
    assert_not retreat.save, "Saved a retreat without a type"
  end

  test "retreat can have a tagline, description, schedule and available" do
    retreat = retreats(:all_attributes)
    assert retreat.save, "Retreat failed to save"
  end

  test "retreat type should be from the provided list" do
    retreat = retreats(:invalid_type)
    assert_not retreat.save, "Some other retreat got saved. It shouldn't 
     have gotten saved."
  end

  test "retreat can have many testimonials" do
    retreat = retreats(:one)
    retreat.testimonials << Testimonial.new(statement: 'this is my 
      testimonial', participant_name: 'abc')
    assert retreat.save, "Retreat did not save with the testimonials."
  end

  test "retreat can have many dates" do
    retreat = retreats(:one)
    retreat.dates.create({date: '02-08-2012'})
    retreat.dates.create({date: '02-08-2013'})
    assert retreat.save, "Retreat with multiple dates is not saving"
    assert_equal(2, retreat.dates.length, "Retreat isn't saving multiple 
       dates.")
  end
```

I am looking for advice on what kind of test cases should I write tests for. I feel that some of my test cases are unnecessary. Like test cases for validation make sense but testing if I can add multiple testimonials makes me uncomfortable.

I can rewrite the first two test cases like this:

```
test "retreat title and type_of must not be empty" do
  retreat = Retreat.new
  assert retreat.invalid?
  assert retreat.errors[:title].any?, "Title must exist"
  assert retreat.errors[:type_of].any?, "Type must exist"
end
```

What are the best practises for writing unit tests? And how can I write better unit tests?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.betterspecs.org/ helped me a lot to get starte with tests.

I would say stick to testing your business rules. So don't just test save, or relations, because those work and are part of the rails framework. But do test rules like: 'It can have 2 dates' , 'I want to be able to create a retreat and testimonial at the same time'

Comment: Business rules are something like 'A retreat can have many testimonials'? I went through the link but isn't that link for rspec? I was looking for something specific to minitest framework which is the default in Rails.

Comment: The link is indeed for Rspec but it shows best practices which can be applied to any testing framework. Business rules are indeed like: `A retreat can have many testimonials` or `A retreat must have at least one testimonial`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a clearer border between "external" and "internal". Rails itself (or actual ActiveRecord in this regard) does not help here. It pollutes your objects with lots of responsibilities for which it is unclear where they belong: ActiveRecord is not the best interface for testing.

I follow the rule **for unit tests**:

> Test only the own (public) interface and its effect on direct collaborators.

It is common practice to [write unit tests that test only the subject under test (internal) and never more](https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html). Anything that the subject under test, the unit, is collaborating with, is external: they have their own separate unit-tests.

This results in heavy mocking and stubbing. A typical, non-AR, example would be:

```
class BikeShed
  attr_accessor :color, :colorizer
  def initialize(color, colorizer = ColorFactory)
    @color = color
  end

  def discuss
    @color = ColorFactory.random
  end
end
```

A test would look like:

```
class BikeShedTest < TestCase
  describe "#discuss" do
    it "changes color to a random color from ColorFactory" do
      subject.color_factory = stub("DefaultColor")
      subject.color_factory = color_factory
      color_factory.expects(:random).returns(color)

      subject.discuss

      assert_equal color, subject.color
    end
  end

  private

  def subject
    @subject ||= BikeShed.new
  end

  def color
    @color ||= stub("Color")
  end

  def color_factory
    @color_factory ||= stub("ColorFactory")
  end
end
```

I use dependency-injection to pass in all its *collaborators* and only test that the *subject* is interacting with this associations in the proper way. Nothing more. Ever.

And I used `BikeShed` because this is a heavily debated subject; without proper intergration tests this test-style is bad, and it can result in you testing only that you've set up your stubs right. It also can lead to "testing implementation" rather quickly. 
Yet, I really like this style, because it forces you to keep loose coupling and keep the API and responsibilities small, focused and clean. Something that e.g. ActiveRecord breaks.

ActiveRecord pollutes models with a giant heap of responsibilities. Validation, storing, callbacks, marshalling, mapping to view-files, has-many etc, scopes, caching and so on and so on.

Therefore, w.r.t. ActiveRecord (and most Rails objects), I follow:

> Everything Rails' offers in superclasses is a *collaborator*.

I consider `ActiveRecord::Base` as if it is some external API. Like the `ColorFactory` in above example. Eventhough this technically is not really correct: it is part of my API too. Consider this: if you have a `Stripe::Payment` that you inherit, say in your `MonthlyPayment`, you won't test that Stripe is taking funds from your CC correctly, not even that Strip created a proper payment on its servers. So why is this different with your database? ActiveRecord is just a gateway to your Database, like `Stripe::Payment` would be.

So, when testing ActiveRecord, I consider anything ActiveRecord offers, as external API, I mock it out:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base; end
class Retreat < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, presence: true
  scope :nsfw -> { where("title LIKE '%nsfw%'") }
end
```

A test might look like

```
class RetreatTest < TestCase
  describe ".nsfw" do
    it "selects only records whose title includes nsfw" do
      ActiveRecord::Base.expects(:where).with("title LIKE '%nsfw%'")
      subject.nsfw
    end
  end

  describe "#title" do
    it "is validated to be present" do
      subject.title = nil
      subject.validate
      assert_includes subject.errors["title"], "can't be blank"
    end
  end

  private

  def subject
    @subject ||= Retreat.new
  end
end
```

We see three important things here:

1. testing a scope is only a test to determine that we are calling the *external* ActiveRecord API with correct messages and parameters. We can safely assume that ActiveRecord has tests in place to assert that when we call it correctly, it will return the correct attributes from some storage. That is not our responsibility. (But an integration test should assert that the end-result for a user is a properly filtered view or such).
2. testing a *macro* like `validate` merely tests that we have configured our model correct; Unfortunately the API to determine this configuration is horrible so we do run through a validation to see that it sets a certain error on our subject.
3. a uniqueness-validation is harder, we'd need to stub out `ActiveRecord.any?` to return a true and then expect a validation `.error` to appear. For example. But never should we write records to the database and then use that setup to determine validation-errors on our object: that is fragile and we are testing a lot of stuff that completely irrelevant. Such as that it is stored correctly (responsibility of AR, not our model) or that AR uses the correct `where` to determine uniqueness (responsibility of AR/ORM, not our model).

Note that this reeks like "testing implementation, but really it is not: we are testing that an external API is called in a certain way. That is IMO the one (and only) task of unit-tests. Integration tests are there to assert that all these "certain ways" result in the correct behaviour.

Comment: By 'internal' do you mean the Rails framework? And my 'external' do you mean the code that I've written? There are a lot of terms that I don't understand like mocking and stubbing. Do you have any resources for a beginner like me?

Comment: I've updated the answer to cover some of your questions. Some basic terminoligy is found at https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html. But note that several test-frameworks (rspec, you, stupid moron!) uses the terms the exact other way around.